# get a result sql server compare result of aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query

```
    select max(start_time), min(end_time)
    from table t where max(start_time) < min(end_time)
```

i am getting aggregate function not allowed in where clause

how will i compare this

Comment: Use a `having` clause, as I mentioned in the comments on your previous question.

Comment: the logic is wrong it does not display any record

Answer (score 0):

Having *just* aggregate functions will produce just 2 numbers so if first is bigger than the second - of course u won't see any records. You have to add a `group by` field for `having` logic to work.  E.g.

```
select somefield, max(start_time), min(end_time)
from table
group by somefield
having max(start_time) < min(end_time)
```

**Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b220/1**